# iptables redirect IP address

Tags: iptables, tcp

I have an application (mirth) on a server (10.2.2.200) that on port 6661 is receiving an HL7 feed from an egate server from 10.0.1.234 port 56789.  For each message it receives/processes, its generating back an HL7 ACK message to 10.0.1.234 port 56789.  The egate server (which I don't control) isn't getting the ACK messages though, as its expecting to receive them at 10.1.1.111 port 6661.

Would it be possible to setup iptables (on my mirth server -- that is 10.0.2.200) to edit the ACK packets generated by mirth that were originally supposed to go to 10.0.1.234 port 56789 and instead send them to 10.1.1.111 port 6661?

I'm reading up on NAT/iptables ( http://www.karlrupp.net/en/computer/nat_tutorial ), but I'm not sure if its possible at this point and any help would be much appreciated.

Summary of fake IPs:

- Mirth : 10.2.2.200 (listening to port 6661)
- Egate sender: 10.0.1.234 (listening to port 56789)
- Egate wants listening for ACKs: 10.1.1.111 port 6661

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use iptables with the [`--tcp-flags` argument](http://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables):

> --tcp-flags [!] mask comp
>
> Match when the TCP flags are as specified. The first argument is the flags which we should examine, written as a comma-separated list, and the second argument is a comma-separated list of flags which must be set. Flags are: SYN ACK FIN RST URG PSH ALL NONE. Hence the command

```
  iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,ACK,FIN,RST SYN
```

> will only match packets with the SYN flag set, and the ACK, FIN and RST flags unset.

I don't have a linux box handy to gin up the right incantation, but I'd think it would go something like:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --tcp-flags ACK ACK --dest 10.0.1.234 --dport 56789 -j DNAT --to:destination 10.1.1.111:6661
```

Answer (score 1):

More or less your wanting to take advantage of the packet mangling feature of iptables. It involves altering the packets in the prerouting and postrouting tables. You also need to load a custom module when using this feature. I am in no way a pro at iptables, but have dealt with this in the past when I was alot younger. Heres a link to a document describing the process -

There is more on google about mangling packets. Sorry for not being more informative. I hope this help with conquest to take over the world.

www.linuxsecurity.com.br/info/fw/PacketManglingwithiptables.doc

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work (though its not just filtering just ACKs and I am still testing.)

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d 10.0.1.234 --dport 10000:65535 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.1.1.111:6661
```

Comment: I don't believe you *CAN* filter just the (HL7) ACK (message) with iptables -- IPTables doesn't know the content.  This solution redirects all the traffic which may break stuff.  You'd really need something sitting in the middle that is HL7-aware to handle the message routing...